# Unwanted backslash in json when stored in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

I am storing a `json` first in `localstorage` and then again storing it in final `json` but I am getting extra `backslash` in my final `json`. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <script>

    var mi = [{
       "name": "Alex",
       "address": "abc"
       },
       {
        "name": "George",
       "address": "efg"
      }
      ]

    localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(mi))

    var FinalJson = {
             "Collected values" : localStorage.getItem("myData"),
             "Place" : "washington"
            };
    document.write(JSON.stringify(FinalJson));
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output I am getting is:

```
     {"Collected values":"[{\"name\":\"Alex\",\"address\":\"abc\"} {\"name\":\"George\",\"address\":\"efg\"}]","Place":"washington"}
```

Where am i going wrong that I am getting this extra `backslash`. How can I remove the extra `backslashes`? P.S. I don't want to directly store the variable `mi` in my `FinalJson`, as it contains some more complicated values which I have removed here for simplicity.

Comment: It's just escaping the string, try parsing the data back and see if it resolves it self, as you're probably not planning on just throwing the JSON out on the page as a string ?

Comment: Oh, it's double stringified, do `"Collected values" : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myData"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stringified twice

```
var FinalJson = {
     "Collected values" : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myData")),
     "Place" : "washington"
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kh5Br/

Answer (score 3):

```
var mi = [{
     "name": "Alex",
     "address": "abc"
   },
   {
     "name": "George",
     "address": "efg"
   }
];

localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(mi))

var tes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myData")); //It was "work". I thougt you missed that

var FinalJson = {
         "Collected values" : tes,
         "Place" : "washington"
        };
document.write(JSON.stringify(FinalJson));
document.write(tes);
```